# Struggling getting random string from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, random

Ok, I've got this array and I want to get a random array from it every time.
I have looked up and got an answer, but it shows not what I want on my website.

The array is in this variable called `$statusarray` and when I print_r this variable, I get this:

```
Array(
    [0] => aa
    [1] => bb
    [2] => cc
    [3] => dd
    [4] => ee
    [5] => ff
)
```

I know that you do `$randomstatus = array_rand($statusarray, 1);` to get one random entry from the array as written on http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php.
and I print_r or echo it.

However, when I do it, it comes up with a random number from 1-5 and then followed by `NULL`

What is wrong with my code, or is there another way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php. It says that array_rand just returns an index, so if you want a value, you have to tell the array: `$statusarray[$index]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$statusarray = array('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff');
$randomstatus = array_rand($statusarray, 1);
echo $statusarray[$randomstatus];
```

Comment: Why do you put 2 on the second line. I thought that gives you 2 entries out of the array. However, when I do that on the website, only one comes up. Can you explain the programme logic behind that?

Comment: @MasayukiTonoki yes, the second parameter `2` will return 2 entries. I have  updated my answer.

Comment: I don't know why, but I get a NULL after the string for some reason. Would you know a reason why? and I have to put 2 or else only NULL comes up

Comment: Nevermind about the NULL bit, but I still need to put 2 or I won't get a entry from the array.

Comment: Yes you need to put 2

Comment: But I thought that is supposed to return 2 entries. Or is that the rule?

Comment: @MasayukiTonoki 2 will return two entries as `array` but if you put 1 it will `return sting`. I have updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$randomstatus = array_rand($statusarray, 1);
```

this will return the array keys. for array values you have to use

```
echo $statusarray[$randomstatus];
```

the above line will echo the array value

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't work. It says Warning: Illegal offset type

Answer (score 0):

As another variant - you can use `shuffle()` method for your array. Probably it would be easier..
See documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Doesn't that just shuffle the order of the array, not give a random string from the array.

Comment: You told: `I want to get a random array from it every time` :) But even if you want to get only one random element form array - you can use shuffle too. For example `suffle($array); $randomElement = $array[0]`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Made a mistake. :0